# Dropdown menu with hover/mouseover event in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was trying to make and hover dropdown menu but I cant, well not really, I can make that the menu toggle just the specific items, with my code show all the items available:

Code here:

```js
$(document).on('ready', function(){
       var timeout = 0;
       $('.nav').hover(function(){
            $('.dropdown-menu').slideDown('fast');
       },function(){
             timeout = setTimeout(hideMenu,300);
        });
    
       $(".dropdown-menu").hover(function(){
           clearTimeout(timeout);
       },function(){
           hideMenu();
       });
    });
    
    function hideMenu(){
        $(".dropdown-menu").slideUp('fast');
     }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar  navbar-static-top navbar-default">
                <div class="container">
                  <div id="cls">
                    <div class="navbar-header center">
                      <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a href="/"><img class="logo" src="paruno_logo.png"></a>
                        <ul id="main-menu" class="nav navbar-nav ref">
                          <li class="dropdown dropdown-large option">
                            <a id="drop-to" href="/femenino/calzado" class="dropdown-toggle firstTextOption" data-toggle="dropdown">GIRL</a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-large row change-f">
                                <li class="n-smasd">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="dropdown-header title"><a href="/femenino/calzado/zapato">Zapatos</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="dropdown-header title"><a href="/femenino/calzado/botin">Botines</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="dropdown-header title"><a href="/femenino/calzado/bota">Botas</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="dropdown-header title"><a href="/femenino/calzado/sandalia">Sandalias</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="dropdown-header title"><a href="/femenino/calzado/tenis">Tenis</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                              </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li class="dropdown dropdown-large option hidden-sm hidden-xs">|</li>
                          <li class="dropdown dropdown-large option">
                            <a id="drop-to" href="/masculino/calzado" class="dropdown-toggle firstTextOption" data-toggle="dropdown">HUMMIE</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-large row change-f">
                                <li class="col-sm-3 option-sm">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="dropdown-header title"><a href="/masculino/calzado/casual">Casuales</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="dropdown-header title"><a href="/masculino/calzado/mocasin">Mocasines</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="col-sm-3 option-sm">
                                  <ul>
                                      <li class="dropdown-header title"><a href="/masculino/calzado/bota">Botas</a></li>
                                  </ul>
                                  <ul>
                                      <li class="dropdown-header title"><a href="/masculino/calzado/tenis">Tenis</a></li>
                                  </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li class="dropdown dropdown-large option hidden-sm hidden-xs">|</li>
                          <li class="dropdown dropdown-large option">
                            <a id="drop-to" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle firstTextOption" data-toggle="dropdown">SOULCREATION</a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-large row change-f">
                                <li class="col-sm-3 option-sm">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="dropdown-header title"><a href="/rapsodia_lookbook_fall16/">ANGER</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="col-sm-3 option-sm">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="dropdown-header title"><a href="/rapsodia-lookbook-2/">SOUL</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="col-sm-3 option-sm">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="dropdown-header title"><a href="/revista-rapsodia-1/">URBAN</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="col-sm-3 option-sm">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="dropdown-header title"><a href="/revista-rapsodia-1/">ART</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="col-sm-3 option-sm">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="dropdown-header title"><a href="/revista-rapsodia-1/">ALAN ARROUND THE MUNDO</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                              </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li class="dropdown dropdown-large option hidden-sm hidden-xs">|</li>
                          <li class="dropdown dropdown-large option">
                            <a id="drop-to" href="/femenino/calzado" class="dropdown-toggle firstTextOption"> MAGNIFICIENT </a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>                
                      </div>
                    <!-- /MB -->
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

To give more information, I use Bootstrap to make a responsive `navbar` and I don't want to use the Javascript from Bootstrap beacuse I want to get a pure Javascript.

Comment: I didn't get full understanding on what is your question is. What do you want to achieve and what does not work?

Comment: If you "want to get a pure Javascript", why do you use jQuery?

Comment: @maximelian1986, I can't show just only one submenu, when I try to open one of the elements, all the elements open at the same time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, don't know what do you mean by pure js when you using Jquery and bootstrap (which is using Jquery as well). But add that function to your code

```
$(document).on('mouseover','.dropdown-toggle',function(e){
    $(this).parent('li').children('ul').slideDown('fast');
});
```

This will open dropdown menu. For hiding it you can research more.

Also I noticed that you have several elements with same id="drop-to". Id value should be **unique**! Name and class can be same on multiple elements.

Comment: It works, only missing when the mouse leave close the dropdown but it doesnt matter, than you!!